# Set Selected item color on ListView with Alternating items Win7

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I am having an issue with a WPF ListView control where the selected item color is not respected on Windows 7 (Aero), but works on Server 2008.

[image: Windows Server 2008 Screen Shot]   [image: Windows 7 / Aero Screen Shot]

The first picture is from the Windows Server 2008 machine, with 'Bacon' option clicked. Then I ran the same program on Windows 7, and clicked the 'Bacon' option.

It's pretty apparent that the background I'm setting for the selected item isn't being respected on the Aero theme, but I don't know how to deal with it.

XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFDriver.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="150">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
            <Style.Resources>
                <!-- set the selected item color -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="DeepPink"/>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.InfoBrush}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListView Name="lvItems" AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Joop}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Widget" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Widget}" ></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Coin" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Coin}" ></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WPFDriver
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class Thing
        {
            public string Widget { get; set; }
            public string Coin { get; set; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Thing> Joop { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
            Joop = new ObservableCollection<Thing>();

            Joop.Add(new Thing() { Widget = "Code", Coin = "Quarter" });
            Joop.Add(new Thing() { Widget = "Bicycle", Coin = "Nickel" });
            Joop.Add(new Thing() { Widget = "Bacon", Coin = "Dime" });
            Joop.Add(new Thing() { Widget = "A Koda", Coin = "Penny" });
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
First solution proposed by Peter Hansen:
In the ListView style, add both the IsSelected and the HighlightBrushKey

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <!-- set the selected item color (Works for non Aero theme) -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="DeepPink"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.InfoBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
            <!-- set the selected item color (Works for Win7 Aero theme) -->
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DeepPink"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be overriding the `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` value like that, since it is not really reliable. Themes might obtain the color used for selections differently, and that is what you are experiencing now.

Instead you can create a `Trigger` that listens to the `IsSelected` property of the `ListViewItem` and change the color when it is true:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DeepPink" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: This correctly sets the background color for Windows 7 to pink, but the system is using the default highlight color for Server 2008. I added back the `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="DeepPink"/>` and in addition to what you've shown here, I've got a working solution. Thanks. If you've got a better idea for fixing it in Server 2008 (non-Aero theme) I'm all ears.

Comment: You are right. I've looked through some of my code, and you have to do both to make it work for older themes (on Windows XP, Server 2008 etc.) and the new themes (on Windows Vista, 7 and 8 etc.). I don't think there is a better solution unfortunately.